# struts2 form to accept multi language

Tags: utf-8, struts2

I have a form which submit details like name, address, affiliations. Here these inputs will in different language like french, Spanish, German, Russian and so on. I point that these inputs are some time have non English keyboard character and are submitted as different character like &,^ and so on.

for example,

this is the input

> Instituto de Quı´mica, Universidade de Sa˜ o Paulo, Sa˜ o Paulo,
>   Brazil

and this is the data that saved in DataBase while I submit the form

```
Instituto de Qu?´mica, Universidade de Sa˜ o Paulo, Sa˜ o Paulo, Brazil
```

I have set the character set as UTF-8 in database and in jsp page first later I found that struts 2 form has a tag attribute  `acceptcharset="UTF-8"`

and it has been working for only few other language but not for Spanish, Portuguese nad many more.
so what is the solution for this issue?

Comment: just a doubt can you set Tomcat default character encoding to UTF-8?

Comment: do u mean this <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

Comment: check inside your `server.xml` for `<Connector port="8080"/>` and add `<Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>` though port might be different in your case

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi this is not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Fix this by changing UTF-8 in `pageEncoding` and `charset` in HTML page where ever I see this and in `form` i used `acceptcharset="UTF-8"` and last I get issue in storing it in DB even its charset is charset is UTF-8 so I forced DB connection to use UTF-8 by providing `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDB?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8` in connection url

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring filter, and force the encoding to UTF8.
Add this to your web.xml:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: do I need any spring plug in for this?

Comment: you need to add the spring libraries to your project. If you don't use spring injection capabilities into the struts2 actions you don't need the struts-spring-plugin.

Comment: @SathishKumarkk: even if you are not using Spring you can create a simple filter which will set the request encoding before passing control

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi Can you please tell how to do that

Comment: @SathishKumarkk: Spring is open source,, have a look at source code of this filter and you can adapt that to your way.here is the link to source code http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-web/2.5.1/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.java

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi as you have said that without using spring we can do this so tell me how to do it.

Comment: @SathishKumarkk: i already provided the link of that filter, create your own filter and use/adapt that code, map your filter in your web.xml before struts dispatcher filter and you are all set to go

Comment: @Atropo: only if you using spring else there is no benefits of adding extra dependencies for a single filter

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi According to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6929337/896718)  I think I need to create an interceptor instead of filter. Am I right?

Comment: @SathishKumarkk: No create filter so that it should be application to each request being passed to the underlying system

Answer (score 0):

If you need to force jsp to UTF-8 you can write the following in web.xml:

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group > 
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```